# 405 GET method not allowed

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, get

I have a spring boot functionality i dont have any GET method for an specific controller, however, I'm getting this error, is this a bug or do you guys have any idea why this can be happening?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint")
public ModelAndView startCall(HttpServletRequest request) {
.
.
.
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not calling the method by a GET request in any part of my app

Comment: Are you saying you get a GET not allowed on a method that doesn’t allow GETs?

Comment: I'm saying i have that error, but I'm not calling the method in any part of my project with GET, that's why i'm asking if there is  bug or something

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: "I am having the error" ... isnt a problem description we could help with. Normally, the 405 answer comes back from a server to a client. So, your client sends a GET request and gets that error code back. So you have to look into what your client is doing?!

Comment: *"I'm not calling the method by a GET request in any part of my app"* Are you absolutely **sure** about that? You haven't shared the client code that's getting the error, so you surely haven't proved that to *us*.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending a GET request to a controller that only handles POST... and `GET<>POST`

Comment: I dont have any GET call in my project, it is not that

Comment: @DuSant It is not what the SERVER knows. It is about what potential clients sent to your server?!

Comment: @DuSant yes i understand but someone is sending GET and when that happens you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

this is an error from http server he can't find an implementation of the Get method so the server respond with this error , you have nothing to do with this error but if you want to remove this error you can redirect the request to an error page.
you should check this for more info : [Spring boot REST](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#_create_a_resource_controller)